# How to add a value coming from inside a compose function into a dataStore

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, android-jetpack-datastore

I am building an Android app that uses Compose and Navigation. On one screen I have several form fields each in its own composable function, of which I want to store the values. I have managed to do so for a single form field that is in the main screen function as in [this example](https://github.com/developerchunk/DataStorePreferences-Jetpack) like this:

```
@Composable
fun Screen1(navController: NavController) {
    val context = LocalContext.current 
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val dataStoreName = StoreName(context)
    val savedName = dataStoreName.getValue.collectAsState(initial = "")
    Column( ) { 
        val patientName = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
        Button(onClick = {scope.launch {dataStoreName.saveValue(patientName.value)}
            navController.navigate(Screen.Screen2.route) })  {
                Text(text = "Save & Next")}
        OutlinedTextField( value = patientName.value,
            label = { Text(text = "Name") },
            onValueChange = {  patientName.value = it  }) 
        Text(text = "Current information stored: " + savedName.value)  }  }
```

However, it is not clear to me how to adapt it when I have several fields each in it's own composable function. When I place the mutableState variable inside the textfield function it is not recognized by the code in the save button, and when I place it outside, the variable is not recognized by the textfield function...
This is one of the textfield function as I have them now, which I would call inside the column in the Screen1 function:

```
@Composable
fun PatientNameField() {
    val patientName by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = patientName.value,
        label = { Text(text = "Name") },
        onValueChange = { patientName.value = it   }    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your current problem you can pass the `patientName` as a parameter to your `PatientNameField` composable as shown below. This will help to maintain the state of `patientName` across your `Screen1` and `PatientNameField` composables.

```
@Composable
fun Screen1(navController: NavController) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val dataStoreName = StoreName(context)
    val savedName = dataStoreName.getValue.collectAsState(initial = "")
    Column {
        val patientName = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
        Button(onClick = {
            scope.launch { dataStoreName.saveValue(patientName.value) }
            navController.navigate(Screen.Screen2.route)
        }) {
            Text(text = "Save & Next")
        }

        //pass the patientName as a parameter to your Composable
        PatientNameField(patientName)

        Text(text = "Current information stored: " + savedName.value)
    }
}

@Composable
fun PatientNameField(patientName: MutableState<String>) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = patientName.value,
        label = { Text(text = "Name") },
        onValueChange = { patientName.value = it   }    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! Now I still need to figure out how to do it for multiple boolean values from a checklist. So the variable would have to be a list. I will try it, and post a new question if I don't manage :-)